# how parse asp.net mvc razor view (cshtml) like html parser in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to parse razor view file in c# . I have also used Html Agility Pack to parse razor view file but it failed to save correct file contents.

Basically i want to change some html elements inner html by server side using c#

```
<div id="content1">
<p>this contents i want to change </p>
<span>contes</span>
</div>
```

i want to change content1 inner html by c# like this

```
<div id="content1">
    <span>@Function.gethtml()</span>
    </div>
```

I have used html agility pack to change inner html contents but it is not parsing razor syntax function like

@Url.Content("abc.css") and other function

**For more information**

I have created a project in asp.net mvc3 for shoes and garments shops.Now i want to change css and html dynamically.i want to extract inner html from any **html template file** where element id will be "**content1**" and place this inner html in **cshtml file** where element id is "**content1**

**Simply i want razor file parser that can parse both html and razor syntax like html parser**

Is there any way to parse razor view file and it html elements.
Any Other solution

Answer (score -1):

You want to access / modify razor content using server side content.

But MVC is a different way of building websites/applications to webforms.

There are now server side controls or webcontrols. You can use JQuery to do same.

Comment: I think you cant get my question simply i want razor file parser that can parse both html and razor syntax like html parser